# Why does one array_walk work and the other array_walk does not?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to convert some MS Word characters from a user submitted form.

Using array_walk to iterate through the $_POST variables seems to be the best way to do this, but it isn't working when I call my "sanitize_msword_characters" function.

The following array_walk calling my "sanitize_msword_characters" function does not result in any characters being replaced:

```
array_walk('sanitize_msword_characters', $_POST);

function sanitize_msword_characters($data = '')
{
    $data= str_replace("‘", "'", $data);
    $data= str_replace("’", "'", $data);
    $data= str_replace("”", '"', $data);
    $data= str_replace("“", '"', $data);
    $data= str_replace("–", "-", $data);
    $data= str_replace("—", "--", $data);
    $data= str_replace("…", "...", $data);

    return $data;
}
```

The following array_walk does work, but I have to place it in every php file that processes a form:

```
array_walk($_POST, function(&$value, &$key) {
    $value = str_replace("‘", "'", $value);
    $value = str_replace("’", "'", $value);
    $value = str_replace("”", '"', $value);
    $value = str_replace("“", '"', $value);
    $value = str_replace("–", "-", $value);
    $value = str_replace("—", "--", $value);
    $value = str_replace("…", "...", $value);
});
```

I tried to place the above array_walk code in a function (see below), but then it didn't make the replacements, although no errors were produced.

```
function sanitize_msword_characters($data = '')
{
    array_walk($data, function(&$value, &$key) {
        $value = str_replace("‘", "'", $value);
        $value = str_replace("’", "'", $value);
        $value = str_replace("”", '"', $value);
        $value = str_replace("“", '"', $value);
        $value = str_replace("–", "-", $value);
        $value = str_replace("—", "--", $value);
        $value = str_replace("…", "...", $value);
        $value = str_replace("–", "--", $value);
    });

    return $data;
}
```

My question is what can I do to have a function that will give me the intended results using array_walk?

Comment: use `array_walk($_POST, sanitize_msword_characters);`, which seems to be closer to the expected syntax.

Comment: The first example is not working because the parameters are in the wrong order. Review the documentation for [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) here. The first parameter is the array and the second parameter is the callback function. Also, your callback function should be the name of a function not a string (i.e. `sanitize_msword_characters` not `"sanitize_msword_characters"`).

Comment: @njzk2 I had the parameters switched when playing with array_map which apparently has the parameters opposite of array_walk ...after changing the syntax, it still does not work.

Comment: Update: I got the array_walk to work, but only if the function it calls is in the same file. If the function is in another file and included, it does not work, and produces no errors. So, I guess the question is why won't the array_walk work if the function it calls is in another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The reason the array_walk was not working when included in a separate functions file was because the format of my functions.php file was 1252(ANSI-Latin I). I converted it to UTF-8 and now it works. The special MS characters were not being encoded properly when the format was 1252(ANSI-Latin I) which resulted in array_walk not working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.  First the parameter order is wrong in the `array_map` call.  Second, you need to pass the item value as a reference in order to change it:

```
array_walk($_POST, 'sanitize_msword_characters');

function sanitize_msword_characters(&$data)
{
    $data= str_replace("‘", "'", $data);
    $data= str_replace("’", "'", $data);
    $data= str_replace("”", '"', $data);
    $data= str_replace("“", '"', $data);
    $data= str_replace("–", "-", $data);
    $data= str_replace("—", "--", $data);
    $data= str_replace("…", "...", $data);
}
```

I would shorten it:

```
function sanitize_msword_characters(&$data)
{
    $s = array("‘","’","”","“","–","—","…");
    $r = array("'","'",'"','"',"-","--","...");
    $data = str_replace($s, $r,  $data);
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b1b63433c9faa71bfca569b4a3c1a5f27ffde3f)

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work. The parameters were switched when playing with array_map ...after changing the syntax, it still does not work. The only way I can get it to work is using the second sample in my OP.

Comment: Works great, see the DEMO.  Maybe your `$_POST` doesn't contain what you think or is multi-dimensional?

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I discovered it does work if I include the function in the same file, but when I have the function in my functions.php file, it does not work. Any idea what could prevent it from working when not in the same file? I checked for other functions with same name that could be conflicting with it but none were found.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Thanks ...there are some NOTICE: undefined variable: errors but nothing related to the array_walk. I'm lost as to why array_walk will not see my function when it's in a separate file. The functions.php is included using require_once.